# Java new path not getting detected in Windows

Tags: java, configuration

Due to lack of space I uninstalled Java from my C: Drive and instead installed in D: drive. While doing this, I re-configured the JAVA_HOME, Path environment variables. However, when I do echo %JAVA_HOME% it displays the old path i.e. `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_73`
whereas the new path is `D:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_92`

Further, java -version and javac -version display the correct version of java which is 8.92 (older one was 8.73)

Pls suggest how to change configure java correctly. I am using Windows Server 2008 R2

Comment: try `where java` to know where he's getting the `java` command from when you check the version.

Comment: JAVA_HOME variable is not used for running java from console - you're terminal looks through PATH variable looking for java executable. if you want to see reconfigured JAVA_HOME variable and you're absolutely sure that you've changed variable value - just try to restart you console

Comment: In system32 folder I had javaws. I replaced it with my 8.92's javaws. Still the issue is there. Then I checked ProgramData\Oracle. Now this one is getting created in C: Drive for some reason, but has the correct shortcuts. I am clueless what is going wrong. Why Java is not getting detected in D: drive?

Comment: I did restart the cmd window

Comment: @l00tr I did check the link. I still have my environment variables in sysdm.cpl

Comment: The C:\ProgramData\Oracle is created so the latest java you installed can be found. Each time you install java, the installer will also reset the shortcuts in C:\ProgramData\Oracle (unless there is a way to tell him not to)

Comment: Output from `where java`:  `C:\Users\Administrator>where java
C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath\java.exe
D:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_92\bin\java.exe`

Comment: You've written that the console was restartet, but did you try a server restart (if it is possible at the moment)? In your case it is probably overkill and should not be necessary, but maybe it helps because everything will be loaded freshly.

Comment: Well, yes, I did restart the server too :(

Comment: OK! last resort: try `set | find "JAVA_HOME"`, it will give you the list of all variables containing "JAVA_HOME" in their name.

Comment: It is an AWS instance actually. I can just shutdown/restart the EC2 instance itself

Comment: Output of set command: `C:\Users\Administrator>set | find "JAVA_HOME"
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_73`

Comment: Ok, I rebooted the machine, restarted the Ec2 instance, but still the same thing :(

Comment: One more thing: C:\Windows\system is empty and C:\Windows\System32 does not have any java exe's at the moment. is this correct?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I guess I figured out why this was happening :)

From the previous java installation (8.73), the JAVA_HOME was set in Env Variables > User Vraiables for Administrator

and I had created under System Variables.

Not sure which is the correct place, but I removed it from user variables now and it is all set. (Appreciate if someone could suggest the right place)
Thank you all for your inputs

Comment: If you define it as system variable, all users will have access to it. A variable defined in a user's envirenment will only be accessible for the user. In your case I'd say that it should be a system variable so all programs that will need the JAVA_HOME variable will have access to it. It depends however on the situation: if you have as constraint that only programs ran as admin should have access to it, you should put it in the admin's environment (but don't forget to hide or secure the java directory).

Comment: As you've seen, if you define a variable in the system environment, but it's also defined in a user environment, the user in question will see his personal value but the other users will have the value from the system environment. This is to allow users to customize his environment.